# Angular JS md-autocomplete displays value for selected option as [object Object]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am having the md-autocomplete in combiation with md-chips. When I select a option instead of showing the selected option text, it displays `[object Object]`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOxIZ.png)

**OPTIONS**

```
[
  {
    "id": "000467369117",
    "name": "000467369117",
    "value": "000467369117",
    "subName": "Test 1",
    "allowOne": true
  },
  {
    "id": "000467369118",
    "name": "000467369118",
    "value": "000467369118",
    "subName": "Test 2",
    "allowOne": true
  }
]
```

**SNIPPET**

```
  <md-chips class="flex-chips"
    md-require-match="$ctrl.isMatchOnly"
    md-add-on-blur="true"
    md-max-chips="{{$ctrl.inputMaxChips}}"
    md-transform-chip="$ctrl.transformChip($chip)"
    name="{{$ctrl.inputName}}"
    md-on-add="$ctrl.onSelectionChange(); console.log('on-add event triggered');"
    md-on-remove="$ctrl.onSelectionChange(); console.log('on-remove event triggered');"
    ng-model="$ctrl.inputValue"
    readonly="$ctrl.isReadOnly">
    <md-autocomplete class="md-block"
      placeholder="{{::$ctrl.inputPlaceholder}}"
      ng-hide="!!$ctrl.inputMaxChips && ($ctrl.inputValue.length >= $ctrl.inputMaxChips - 1)"
      md-autocomplete-snap
      md-delay="500"
      md-search-text="$ctrl.inputSearch"
      md-min-length="0"
      ng-blur="$ctrl.onBlur()"
      md-no-cache="true"
      md-item-text="item.name"
      md-autofocus="$ctrl.isAutofocus"
      md-items="item in $ctrl.getItems($ctrl.inputSearch)">
      <span class="double-line-list-item" layout="column" flex
        ng-switch on="!!item.subName">
        <span class="item-name"
          ng-bind="item.name"
          ng-switch-when="true">
        </span>
        <span class="sub-name" layout="row" layout-align="start center"
          ng-bind-html="item.subName"
          ng-switch-when="true">
        </span>
        <span ng-bind-html="item.name" ng-switch-default></span>
      </span>
    </md-autocomplete>
    <md-chip-template>
      <span class="company-select" ng-bind-html="$chip.name"></span>
    </md-chip-template>
  </md-chips>
```

Tried checking if I am missing something from the doc also took help help of ChatGPT, but no luck :(

Comment: please share working example on jsfiddle or stack overflow code editor for debugging!

Comment: From that screenshot, it seems as if you're not populating the autocomplete correctly. For example, if the source for your autocomplete is something along the lines of `tmp ={"foo":"bar","lorem":"ipsum"}`, the screenshot seems to suggest that you're doing something like `document.getElementById("yourElem").value(tmp)`. But this is all guesswork. As @NarenMurali said, please create a working example which illustrates the problem. If your data is coming from the outside (database, API call, etc), create a dummy variable holding what would normally be the response.